# how to format the date in various formats?

Tags: c#, formatting

I noticed today that in my twitter app on WP7, the twits are shown and their times are listed. But, here is what I really liked:

If a twit was made in the last few seconds, the listbox item displays for eg. 5 secs ago.
If it was made in last few mintues, it shows for eg.  23 min ago.
Same way, shows the word today
If it was on any prior dates, it shows the actual date time.

This type of formatting would apply to any platform (Outlook does similar things).  Has anyone written an extension method or a helper function that they can share to achieve this kind of output?

Thanks,
Pratik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Mitchell had an article featured on the homepage of www.asp.net the other day which covered formatting dates.

The article was a pretty standard run through of the various formatting strings you can use but about two thirds in he discusses a custom method he has created to solve this kind of problem called `.ToRelativeDateString()`. The implementation is included in the downloadable sample attached to the article:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131217/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111010-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using java but [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.com/prettytime/) is the library if you are.
You can also achieve this to certain extent using [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) or its .net equvivalent [noda-time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/). Below is the e.g. of using joda-time to print

> **On Tuesday at 2PM**

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2005, 9, 20, 14, 30, 0, 0);
DateTimeFormatter f = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
.appendLiteral(“On “)
.appendDayOfWeekText()
.appendLiteral(“ at “)
.appendClockhourOfHalfday(1)
.appendHalfdayOfDayText()
.toFormatter();

String str = f.print(dt);
// Output: On Tuesday at 2PM
```

Comment: Pangea, I should have mentioned that I am using .NET for this app.  Thanks for this information though.  I am sure I will use this some day and that someone else will benefit out of reading your response.

Comment: if your are in .NET then you can use noda-time. the syntax is pretty much the same as I've shown. noda-time is a standard library so try to do a small poc with this and the code from Robin

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a set of classes for this, which integrates with the internationalization in .NET. Since its tied to the culture, you can easily have different variations. Eg "10 seconds ago" if you're English, or "10 sekunder sedan" if you have the Swedish culture set. It's that easy.

You can download it at:

[I18n Extensions - .NET4 Library](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8866426/I18n.Extensions.zip)

Comment: Robin, I am writing my app in .NET and it would be great if you could share that code. Thanks.

Comment: Pratik - I have updated my entry. I have made the library available for you to download.